# Shut down windows server 2008 r2 machine from c# console application

Tags: c#, shutdown, utility

I agreed, we can shut down cleint machines programatically. but suppose my machine is configured with Windows server 2008 r2. to shut down any server machine, is not easy as compare to normal client operating systems machine. 
since we need to stop services,stop running processes and at the end we need to give confirmation to the os that this shutdown process is "planned" for shut down event tracker. so can we do that from c# console application?. What programe i have to do for this?

**Edited:**
I am thankfull for all answers. But one thing i missed while writing the question, this shutdown must perform only when machine is unattended for 120 mins. so is there any another process where i can check the attendance-unattendace of machine ? so that i would call shutdown process.

Comment: Please review edited query....

Comment: Can you elaborate attendance-unattendance? User logged off 120 minutes go, User loggen on but not keyboard/mouse input?

Comment: you are absolutely right, no inputs since 120 mins

Comment: I think you can check the screensaver state using c#, but personally I´d suggest you´ll try using standard windows components (Energy saving settings, etc) to fullfill your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using the [`shutdown.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) command of Windows:

```
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/l /t:0");
```

If you simply want to get rid of the dialog for entering a shutdown reason you can configure your Registry accordingly:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability]
"ShutdownReasonOn"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an application called [Shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) that you can invoke using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

it can also restart the machine, set log messages and restart remote machines (i think)

Answer (score 1):

Is shutdown.exe not working for you? See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `Process.Start("shutdown",...);`(where ...- is string of parameters) on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

UAC on Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista and Windows 7 blocks "shutdown.exe" from non-elevated processes.
Try running your application with administrator rights.

Answer (score 1):

In Sysinternals Suite there is all the necessary tools to kill the processes, shutdown services and shutdown the OS. If you did not look it , you would from here :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

Answer (score 1):

You can [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.initiatesystemshutdownex) [`InitiateSystemShutdownEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to specify a reason & message for event tracking & as well as management for the UI dialog.